# Excel VBA To Split Workbook Every 4 Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains about 100 worksheets.  I want to create 25 individual workbooks that contain 4 sheets each.  I am trying to write an Excel VBA `foor loop` that will do such - but it is generating a workbook for every 1 page.

```
totalPages = PDDoc.GetNumPages

For i = 1 To totalPages - 4 
    'This is where you would add the workbook and transfer the page
Next i
```

Comment: You need to create a inner loop that move 4 sheets or create a single instruction to move 4 sheets.

Comment: @DavidG. - I obviously do not have a firm a grasp on this concept as I thought I did then.

Comment: What is the instruction you are using that creates 1 workbook for each worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub SplitPages()
   Dim i As Integer

   Dim wb As Workbook

   For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If i Mod 4 = 1 Then
           Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        End If
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy wb.Worksheets(1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

You have to copy to avoid messing up the count, and the new workbooks have an extra sheet - but a quick

```
  for each wb in workbooks:wb.sheets("sheet1").delete:next wb
```

will fix that